# I cant print a number inside a formatted MessageBox

Tags: winapi, unicode, printf, messagebox

The following code does not work as it should.  `%i` does not connect with its variable.

```
#include<Windows.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<tchar.h>

/*       SCREENSIZE.C

    This project contains the code that Programming Windows
    book by Charles Petzold is using.

*/


int cdecl MessageBoxPrintfW(TCHAR *msgBoxTitle, TCHAR *msgBoxFormat, ...)
{
    //define buffer
    TCHAR msgBoxBuffer[1024];

    //define iteration pointer
    va_list argPtr;

    //start iteration
    va_start(argPtr, msgBoxFormat);

    /*int _vsnwprintf_s(
    wchar_t *const _Buffer,
    const size_t _BufferCount,
    const size_t _MaxCount,
    const wchar_t *const _Format,
    va_list _ArgList)
    */

    _vsntprintf_s(msgBoxBuffer, sizeof(msgBoxBuffer) / sizeof(TCHAR), (sizeof(msgBoxBuffer) / sizeof(TCHAR)) - 1, msgBoxFormat, argPtr);

    //end iteration 
    va_end(argPtr);

    //Use return type to pass preconfigured MessageBox(0,"Text","Title",MB_OKCANCEL);
    //Whe we use L before a string example: L"text" it is considered UNICODE format.

    return(MessageBox(0, msgBoxFormat, msgBoxTitle, MB_OKCANCEL));
}

int WINAPI WinMain(
    HINSTANCE hInstance,
    HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
    LPSTR pCmdLine,
    int iCmdShow)
{
    int cxScreen, cyScreen;
    cxScreen = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN);
    cyScreen = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN);

    MessageBoxPrintfW(TEXT ("SCREENSIZE"), TEXT("The screen is %i pixels wide by %i pixels high."), cxScreen, cyScreen);

    return(0);
}
```

Why does this happen?

Below is the output that I get:

[image: output]

Comment: You are displaying the format, not the buffer.

Comment: and what you want ? you not use `msgBoxBuffer` but display `msgBoxFormat` instead

Comment: Thank you Remy for helping with the edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
TCHAR msgBoxBuffer[1024];
_vsntprintf_s(msgBoxBuffer,...
...
return(MessageBox(0, msgBoxFormat, msgBoxTitle, MB_OKCANCEL));
```

Note that you are writting to `msgBoxBuffer`, but you never use `msgBoxBuffer`. So your message box doesn't change anything. Try the following instead:

```
int MessageBoxPrintfW(const TCHAR *msgBoxTitle, const TCHAR* msgBoxFormat, ...)
{
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, msgBoxFormat);

    int len = _vsctprintf(msgBoxFormat, args) + 1; // add terminating '\0'
    TCHAR *buf = new TCHAR[len];
    _vstprintf_s(buf, len, msgBoxFormat, args);

    int result = MessageBox(0, buf, msgBoxTitle, MB_OKCANCEL);

    delete[]buf;

    return result;
}
```

For `C` version use `malloc(len * sizeof(TCHAR))` instead of `new`, and use `free` instead of `delete[]`

Comment: Omg you are correct guys, I was confused and wrote the name of the parameter instead of the actual buffer and then I just couldn`t see it.I took for granted that this senstence was correct.

Comment: Note that if you are going to use `new TCHAR[]` then it would be better to use `std::vector<TCHAR>` or even `std::basic_string<TCHAR>`, then you don't need to call `delete[]` manually. On the other hand, this code is in a file with a `.C` file extension so presumably it uses C instead of C++.

Comment: You are correct Remy.I do not know C++ and I do not want to use it until I have mastered C in a degree.So everything I do I try to keep it as much pure C as possible.I think that i should be very comfortable with C and then move to C++...at least that`s how i feel.

Comment: If you were using *.c extension then `new` operator wouldn't work either. You seem to be using C++, you should stick to it, unless you really need C. Maybe you are talking about avoidance of `std` standard library. I probably should have used `std::vector` here and saved a couple of lines.

Comment: By the way, for debugging purposes you can also use `OutputDebugString` or just put a break point at the variables which you want inspect.